# Using and designing asynchronous APIs with naturally synchronous parts

Tags: c++, asynchronous-programming

I've been programming for a long time, but very rarely with anything asynchronous (and not often with anything to do with multithreading, either).

Mostly for the fun of it, I'm writing a program to download song lyrics, and save them to music files (via e.g. ID3v2 tags). I have most of that in place by now: I have two classes that handles downloading (one per site the program supports), plus the code necessary to write the tags to files.
The design I wanted from the beginning was fairly simple and synchronous; I had planned to create a synchronous/blocking API to download lyrics, and start such tasks in background threads to keep the UI alive.

The idea was that the class that wants to fetch lyrics would create a `LyricFetcher` instance, and call `string LyricFetcher::fetchLyrics(string artist, string title)`. That, in turn, tries fetching the lyrics from each site in order, using something like

```
for (Site *site : sites) {
    lyrics = site->fetchLyrics(artist, title);
    if (successfully downloaded lyrics)
        return lyrics;
}
return (didn't find anything);
```

The problems appeared when I realized that the only APIs I could use to fetch data from the internet were asynchronous; you'd set up a request, and tell it (via signals and slots) to tell you when it's done.
With that, I couldn't simply return the lyrics as a string.
As a workaround, I designed the API to use a callback, which the site-specific code calls when it has either finished the download, or failed, i.e. something like `void LyricFetcher::fetchLyrics(string artist, string title, function<void(string)> callback)`.
The callback was then forwarded to the site-specific classes, which have the same type signature as the `fetchLyrics` above.

That worked fine for a single site, but I ran in to new problems trying to implement the multi-site pseudocode above.
I can't use the pseudocode, since `site->fetchLyrics` would return immediately.
The only "solution" I came up with was to use nested callbacks, which is horrible.

```
void LyricFetcher::fetchLyrics(string artist, string title, function<void(string)> callback) {
    site1->fetchLyrics(artist, title, [=](string lyrics) {
        if (did match)
            callback(lyrics);
        else {
            site2->fetchLyrics(artist, title, [=](string lyrics) {
               ...
```

Not only is this ugly, but it also means you can't iterate through the sites in a simple loop. (I'm not even sure it'd work at all.)

What's a good way to design around issues like these?
The "user facing" API of `LyricFetcher::fetchLyrics` should preferably either be synchronous (with the lyrics as a simple return value), or use signals/slots to signal completion (and transfer results).

FWIW, this is in C++ with Qt (C++14, Qt 5.6), but I tried to stick with a C++y pseudocode in the post.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225372/waiting-for-multiple-futures

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, but I'm not sure that applies to this problem. The problem here isn't about starting many tasks and waiting for them, but about running callback/signal-based in a sequential manner. I'm not even sure how to use futures with them (if that's applicable).

Comment: Use promises to emulate synchronous flow in asynchronous context.

Comment: what @Basilevs said: futures/promises/async exist to make asynchronous code look like synchronous code

Comment: If however you want to ask each site in sequence then you don't need any asynchronicity in processing beyond waiting the thread you start on while the fetch is occuring

Comment: @Caleth Hmm, perhaps this is more of a framework question, then. I'm not sure how to wait on the processing, regardless if I use callbacks or signals for the async part. Apparently waiting for a Qt signal with a event loop is bad practice and can cause bugs, and busy waiting is obviously not very nice, either.

Comment: The general form of not using the UI thread for waits is grabbing any other thread (from a pool or just spawned, conceptually doesn't matter) and having that do the waiting for you. Iirc one of the things future is templated on is where to get a thread from.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem here isn't about starting many tasks and waiting for them, but about running callback/signal-based in a sequential manner.

Use a concurrent function which takes the function which creates the ordered structure and the function which iterates through the ordered structure as arguments. For example, in the concurrent namespace, Qt has a mapReduce method with the following signature

```
QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(const Sequence &sequence, MapFunction mapFunction, ReduceFunction reduceFunction, QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions reduceOptions = UnorderedReduce | SequentialReduce)
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
void addToCollage(QImage &collage, const QImage &thumbnail)
   {
   QPainter p(&collage);
   static QPoint offset = QPoint(0, 0);
   p.drawImage(offset, thumbnail);
   offset += ...;
   }

QImage scaled(const QImage &image)
  {
  return image.scaled(100, 100);
  }

QList<QImage> images = ...;
QFuture<QImage> thumbnails = QtConcurrent::mapped(images, scaled);

QList<QImage> images = ...;
QFuture<QImage> collage = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(images, scaled, addToCollage);
```

> The reduce function will be called once for each result returned by the map function, and should merge the intermediate into the result variable. QtConcurrent::mappedReduced() guarantees that only one thread will call reduce at a time, so using a mutex to lock the result variable is not necessary. The QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions enum provides a way to control the order in which the reduction is done. If QtConcurrent::UnorderedReduce is used (the default), the order is undefined, while QtConcurrent::OrderedReduce ensures that the reduction is done in the order of the original sequence.

**References**

- [Qt 5: QtConcurrent Namespace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html)
- [Qt 4.8: QtConcurrentMap - Concurrent Map and Map-Reduce](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/html/qtconcurrentmap.html)